# Use Google Maps API componentRestrictions for UK postcodes?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, plugins

I'm using a jQuery plugin to handle Google Autocomplete. One of the options is the componentRestrictions. At the moment I'm restricting to Great Britain but there is a suggestion that I can also use postal code to refine even further. I would really like to restrict to Northern Ireland and in absence of a Northern Ireland ISO code I was hoping to use the postcode. ALL postcodes in Northern Ireland start with BT so this may work.

```
$("#geocompleteGB").geocomplete({
details: "form",
types: ["establishment"],
componentRestrictions: {country: "gb"}
});
```

works for now, it returns addresses in all of the UK. Any ideas how I could add the postal_code as a filter? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Places API autocomplete currently doesn't have components filters for localities or postal codes. The only available is country filter. You can see this in the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#ComponentRestrictions

There is a feature request in the public issue tracker to add these filters in autocomplete service:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4433

This feature request was marked as a Neat idea, probably one day Google will have it implemented. You can star a feature request in the public issue tracker to express your interest and receive further updates from Google.

Comment: Thanks. I pretty much came to the same conclusion. I've come up with solution, it's not perfect but it will have to do. The main problem is that 'users' i.e. the businesses that add their details to the directory are less than  complete so it's diffecult to validate certain fields.